# Check if scanner input has "$" char

Tags: java, while-loop

So I am a bit stuck on a project and not sure if I am over thinking this or just brain blocked but here is my situation. I am trying to set up a while loop that checks if there is a next line and if it has not seen a $ symbol.
I know the `hasNextLine` part just confused about the $ symbol

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`string.contains(s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method:

```
Scanner scanner = . . . .;  //(however you are initializing it here)
String nextLine = "";
while((nextLine = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    if(nextLine.contains("$")) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
if (nextLine.indexOf('$') != -1)
```